# npm error ELIFECYCLE while running the test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha-phantomjs

I am using mocha-phantomjs setup for unit testing. I have following package.json scriot to run the tests.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "npm run testFlickr",
"testFlickr": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html" 
}
```

This run ok in browser. And when I run the command `npm test`in cmd, the test run alright but it also gives following error

```
3 passing (5s)
6 failing


npm ERR! flickr-test@ testFlickr: `mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the flickr-test@ testFlickr script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the flickr-test package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls flickr-test
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "testFlickr"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please can anyone tell me how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And when I run the command npm test in cmd, the test run alright

No they aren't. You have 6 failing tests. The exit code of `mocha-phantomjs` is equal to the number of failing tests. Run `mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html` directly and see what is failing. Realize the PhantomJS is a bit different than your browser - you may [have to debug it](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Your script setup is odd. You should just have:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html"
}
```

Then the odd node errors should go away.

Answer (score 30):

I was having this same problem, and what fixed it for me was when I run my unit tests, do **NOT** use

```
npm run test
```

**instead use:**

```
npm test
```

Answer (score 22):

When running `npm test` it squelches `ELIFECYCLE` errors so you never encounter this experience.

[Reference to code](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/b50be6aff34a739ca43de65f546e743d1a9975b9/lib/test.js#L8)

Once you move a test script to a different script-name you'll start seeing `ELIFECYCLE` errors.

My fix is to add a `exit 0` to the end of the command. For your code it would look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run testFlickr",
  "testFlickr": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html; exit 0" 
}
```

Comment: I encountered this issue because I wanted to have multiple test scripts in my `package.json` file.

Comment: Adding `;exit 0` to the end of arbitrary scripts will suppress errors.

Comment: @joemaller not in windows it doesn't.

Comment: Your reference seems very relevant, but it doesn't seem to hold up. I put my tests in the `test` script (i.e. not calling other npm scripts), and still get the ELIFECYCLE error when the only problem is that a test failed. Using `npm v5.6.0`.

Comment: @Tom What's the output you get along with the `ELIFECYCLE` error?A gist might work. Don't forget to remove any sensitive information if you can share your logs.

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem when using `npm run`, it has to do with Mocha exiting with code !== 0 whenever a test fails. If you are on Windows try this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run testFlickr || ECHO.",
  "testFlickr": "mocha-phantomjs ./test/FlickrTest.html || ECHO." 
}
```